# Mail() function in Laragon v.2.2.2 - Wrong encoding after sent

Tags: php, encoding, sendmail, laragon

I am using Laragon v. 2.2.2 - Development environment

I tried to send mail with polish characters **"śćńółęśąśżćźó"**, 
also I added correct headers **"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"** and file encoding to mail,
but in sendmail output logs and on gmail, the message looks like: 
**"L>A?L"AlL,ATL>A.L>LLA?LsAl"**.

Sendmail output logs:

```
17.03.31 16:02:58 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
17.03.31 16:02:58 ** To: ***@gmail.com
17.03.31 16:02:58 ** Subject: test
17.03.31 16:02:58 ** X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:index.php
17.03.31 16:02:58 ** Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
17.03.31 16:02:58 ** 
17.03.31 16:02:58 ** śćńółęśąśżćźó
17.03.31 16:02:58 ** --- MESSAGE END ---


17.03.31 16:02:59 >> Date: Fri, 31 Mar 2017 16:02:59 <EOL>
17.03.31 16:02:59 >> To: ***@gmail.com<EOL>
17.03.31 16:02:59 >> Subject: test<EOL>
17.03.31 16:02:59 >> X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:index.php<EOL>
17.03.31 16:02:59 >> Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8<EOL>
17.03.31 16:02:59 >> <EOL>
17.03.31 16:02:59 >> L>A?L"AlL,ATL>A.L>LLA?LsAl<EOL>
17.03.31 16:02:59 >> .<EOL>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    mail('***@gmail.com', 'test', 'śćńółęśąśżćźó', "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
?>
```

Mails are sent through Laragon email configuration (I am using Gmail)

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. The developer of Laragon did a hotfix for sendmail. Now encoding works fine. Here is the hotfix ( in last post ) https://forum.laragon.org/topic/433/mail-function-trouble-with-encoding

Answer (score 0):

Declare **all** [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) headers including declaration of 8bit encoding.  It should allow your sendmail (SMTP) server conduct conversions required by receiving SMTP server.
Non ASCII characters in email headers require another special encoding ([RFC2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt)).
Due to very ancient tradition emails are expected to contain only 7bit characters by default.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Comment: Wordpress uses this as well. And encoding still is wrong. :/

Comment: Could you include received email in "raw" format? [all headers too]

Comment: Actually, the problem is solved. The developer of Laragon did a hotfix for sendmail. Now encoding works fine. Here is the hotfix ( in last post )
https://forum.laragon.org/topic/433/mail-function-trouble-with-encoding